# Unable to understand pointers in c in a function

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion, function-call

I was reading this code on a website. I am fairly new to programming so please explain in a bit more detail.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// A normal function with an int parameter 
// and void return type 
void fun(int a) 
{ 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // fun_ptr is a pointer to function fun()  
    void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun; 
  
    /* The above line is equivalent of following two 
       void (*fun_ptr)(int); 
       fun_ptr = &fun;  
    */
  
    // Invoking fun() using fun_ptr 
    (*fun_ptr)(10); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

**Doubts-**
I am not able to understand this type of declaration and assignment `void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;` 
I mean that if we declare a data type, then we do it like `int a;` and assign it as `a=10;` but here we are assigning it by writing `(*fun_ptr)(10);`. Kindly help.

Comment: _but here we are assigning it by writing (*fun_ptr)(10);_ `(*fun_ptr)(10);` is not assignment

Comment: before you learn function pointers you need to learn functions and parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets rewrite it a little bit, by using *type-aliases* and some comments:

```
// Define a type-alias names fun_pointer_type
// This type-alias is defined as a pointer (with the asterisk *) to a function,
// the function takes one int argument and returns no value (void)
typedef void (*fun_pointer_type)(int);

// Use the type-alias to define a variable, and initialize the variable
// This defines the variable fun_ptr being the type fun_pointer_type
// I.e. fun_ptr is a pointer to a function
// Initialize it to make it point to the function fun
fun_pointer_type fun_ptr = &fun;

// Now *call* the function using the function pointer
// First dereference the pointer, to get the function it points to
// Then call the function, passing the single argument 10
(*fun_ptr)(10);
```

Hopefully it makes things a *little* clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this record

```
(*fun_ptr)(10);
```

you could just write

```
fun_ptr(10);
```

That is it is a function call of the function `fun` pointed to by the function pointer `fun_ptr` due to the initialization of that pointer in its declaration by the function address

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;
```

In turn this declaration could be written simpler like

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;
```

because a function designator (in this case `fun`) used in expressions as for example an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to the function.

You could use a typedef alias for the function type the following way

```
typedef void Func( int );
```

In this case the above declaration of the function pointer could look simpler like

```
Func *fun_ptr = fun;
```

Here is your program rewritten using a typedef for the function type of the function `fun`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void Func( int );

//  Function declaration without its definition using the typedef
//  This declaration is redundant and used only to demonstrate
//  how a function can be declared using a typedef name
Func fun;

//  Function definition. In this case you may not use the typedef name
void fun( int a )
{
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
}

int main(void) 
{
    //  Declaration of a pointer to function
    Func *fun_ptr = fun;
    
    //  Call of a function using a pointer to it
    fun_ptr( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the meaning of two statments.

`void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;`    this is called declaring and initializing the `fun_ptr` in the same line , this is same as doing `int a = 10;`

`(*fun_ptr)(10);`  is not assignment statement, it is invoking the function `fun` through function pointer `fun_ptr`.

you can also use `typedef` to create a new user defined out of function pointer and use as shown in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an advanced topic if you are new to programming, `fun_ptr` is a pointer to a function.

The declaration:

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;
```

Means `fun_ptr` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` argument and returning `void`, initialize if with a pointer to the function `fun`. (you don't need the `&`)

The line:

```
(*fun_ptr)(10);
```

does not assign anything, it calls the function pointed to by `fun_ptr`, but is way to complex

```
fun_ptr(10);
```

As `fun_ptr` points to `fun` this is equivalant to `fun(10).

Using a function pointer has its use eg in a sort function where the comparison function is passed in as a function pointer so the sorting can be different between calls.
achieves the same thing and is much easier on the eyes.